# Rational Rhapsody Debugging JVM

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, rhapsody

**I am trying to attach a remote debugger to Rational Rhapsody in order to debug a Java plugin I developed.**

The [official guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB2MU_8.1.0/com.ibm.rhp.customization.doc/topics/rhp_t_ext_debugging_within_rhp.html) to do this for Rhapsody 8.1 can states:

> Add the following debug options to the JVM section of the rhapsody.ini
> file:
>
> Options=ClassPath,LibPath,Debug1,Debug2,Debug3
>
> Debug1=-Xnoagent
>
> Debug2=-Xdebug
>
> Debug3=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=6743,server=y,suspend=y

Which seems to be a simple addition of startup arguments for the JVM.

However if I apply this arguments to my Rhapsody it starts as always, however when I open any project containing a plugin call (hence which would start the JVM) it does get stuck while opening it and the application goes to "Not Responding".

I also tried to checkout the "JavaAPILogFile" which without the startup options shows all the Java calls that Rhapsody does to startup a project. If I activate the debugging options this log file stays empty.

Comment: Can you connect with your debugger? I think because you say `suspend=y` it will halt and wait for the debugger to attach.

Comment: Thanks @S.Spieker you totally nailed this. Put this in an answer so I can give you the bounty :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you connect with your debugger? I think because you say `suspend=y` it will halt and wait for the debugger to attach.

As soon as you are connected you can debug your plugin.

Comment: This is a lifesaver thanks!